# Gaining an intuitive understanding of measure & sigma-algebras

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Taking my first course in measure theory.

Consider an example where $\Omega$={all integers from 1 to 16}={1,...,16} where classes of sets are defined by

$C_1$={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

$C_2$={9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}

$C_3$={1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14}

$C_4$={3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16}

So that $\textit{C}$ is the algebra generated by {$C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, $C_4$} and $\textit{A}$=$\sigma[C]$, or the sigma-algebra generated by sets in $\textit{C}$.

Say $\mu$($C_i$)=$\frac{1}{2}$ for $\textit{i}$=2, 3, 4 and $\mu$($C_2$$C_4$)=0.

How would we visualize the sets in the sigma algebra and completed sigma algebra? According to the key, the complete sigma algebra should have $2^{10}$=1024 sets under this measure.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: Finite $\sigma$ algebras such as this have very different structure than the $\sigma$ algebras on continuous structures that we more usually consider in measure theory, so I don't know how good this example is for visualising what's going on.

Basically the question is which integers can be distinguished from which others using these sets: e.g. $1$ and $2$ can't be distinguished, because each $C_i$ either contains both $1$ and $2$ or neither.  So each set of the algebra or $\sigma$-algebra has the same property.
On the other hand, $1$ and $3$ can be distinguished because there is a $C_i$ that contains one and not the other.  If there are $2^{10}$ sets in the $\sigma$-algebra, there must be $10$ equivalence classes (the smallest sets that can be distinguished from each other), and 
every member of the $\sigma$-algebra is the union of some collection of these $10$.

EDIT: Actually this is not the case in the example as you have stated it: there are only $4$ equivalence classes.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\mu$($C_1$$C_3$)=0? Does that mean the intersection of C2 and C4 which is {11, 12, 15, 16} and all the sets associated with these 4 integers have measure 0?

Comment: This set, which is one of the equivalence classes, has measure $0$.  I'm not sure what you mean by "associated with these $4$ integers.